# rsync doesnt copy all files and folders

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync

I have been scratching my head about this issue now for a few days and some serious googling hasn't uncovered the solution.

Basically I am making a full copy of my server, in order to migrate hosts. I have used the following code

```
sudo rsync -azPx -e ssh -azPx --delete-after --exclude-from='/root/rsync-exclude.txt' / root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/
```

This process ran and copied almost everything on the server across, but on closer inspection the contents on the primary server :

```
total 6208
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root      4096 Oct 30  2011 backup
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root      4096 Nov  7 06:30 download 
drwxr-xr-x  2 apache apache  139264 Nov  7 11:42 download_pdf_files
drwxr-xr-x  2 apache apache 4890624 Feb  1 14:31 downloads
drwxr-xr-x 16    503 nobody    4096 Jan 15 16:00 html
drwxr-xr-x  2 apache apache  491520 Feb  1 14:31 pdf_files
drwxrwxrwx  2 apache apache  450560 Feb  1 05:41 pdf_user_files
drwxr-xr-x 14    503 nobody    4096 Sep 22 21:23 test
drwxr-xr-x  2 apache apache    4096 Jan 30 08:17 test_downloads
drwxr-xr-x  2 apache apache  266240 Jan 30 08:17 test_pdf_files
drwxrwxrwx  2 apache apache   65536 Jan 30 08:18 test_pdf_user_files
```

Are not the same as the target server :

```
total 816
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root     4096 Oct 30  2011 backup
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root     4096 Nov  7 06:30 download
drwxr-xr-x 16    503 nobody   4096 Jan 15 16:00 html
drwxrwxrwx  2 apache apache 450560 Jan 31 05:27 pdf_user_files
drwxr-xr-x 14    503 nobody   4096 Sep 22 21:23 test
drwxr-xr-x  2 apache apache   4096 Jan 30 08:17 test_downloads
drwxr-xr-x  2 apache apache 286720 Jan 30 08:17 test_pdf_files
drwxrwxrwx  2 apache apache  65536 Jan 30 08:18 test_pdf_user_files
```

Are there any permissions issues? Missing conditions for rsync or something else? Also, how can I verify that these weren't the only files that were missed?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the contents of /root/rsync-exclude.txt?  I suspect there is a typo in the regular expressions.

Comment: Hi here are the contents of the excludes file:

`/boot
/proc
/sys
/tmp
/dev
/var/lock
/etc/fstab
/etc/mdadm.conf
/etc/mtab
/etc/resolv.conf
/etc/conf.d/net
/etc/network/interfaces
/etc/networks
/etc/sysconfig/network*
/etc/sysconfig/hwconf
/etc/sysconfig/ip6tables-config
/etc/sysconfig/kernel
/etc/hostname
/etc/HOSTNAME
/etc/hosts
/etc/modprobe*
/etc/modules
/etc/udev
/net
/lib/modules
/etc/rc.conf
/etc/sysconfig/network
/etc/resolv.conf`

Answer (score 0):

In new versions you don't need `-e ssh`, in default it use the ssh. Exactly the reason of your problem is the **--exclude-from='/root/rsync-exclude.txt'**. Maybe there is something in that file which exclude syncing your files.

I suggest to use below command:

```
sudo rsync -azPx --remove-source-files --exclude-from='/root/rsync-exclude.txt' / root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/
```